# c++ trying to fail constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm trying to get segment fault, but I can't get it and I wonder why.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace   std;


class A{

 public:
  char *field_;

   A(char *field):field_(field) {
   // I believe(suppose) that it's equal to
   // field_ = field;
   // so actual initial string wasn't copied, only a pointer to it
   }
 void show() {
    cout<<field_<<"\n";
}
};

int main(){

   A *obj;

{
    char *line="I should be freed";
    obj = new (nothrow) A(line);
}

  // After exiting from the previous scope,
  //  char *line variable should be freed. 
  // Constructor of class A didn't make byte for byte 
  //copying, so we cannot have
  // access to it for sure 

for(int i=0;i<4;i++)  // trying to clear stack and erase char *line  variable
 char something[10000];

obj->show(); // and it works correctly!!!! why?


 delete obj;
 return 0;
 }
```

Ok, as I understand it works correctly only because that string wasn't freed from memory.
I.e. we are just lucky.
And here we have undefined behaviour. Am I right?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Why would *adding* something to a stack clear something which already was *in* the stack? (not that the string itself is in the stack)

Comment: if string had been allocated on stack and we went out of the scope, used memory is marked as not necessary, so there is some probability that if we ask for  new memory, old not necessary memory will be used and old string will be erased (of course, it's not guaranteed that  exactly that memory will be taken). E.g. it didn't work in my case, even after I defined it as  char line[80]="I should be freed", in the stack, because that memory is not just taken. But sometimes  it can be overwritten, sometimes not. Correct me, if I'm wrong

Comment: yeah, missed the accolades marking the scope there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't get a segmentation fault because there are no invalid memory references made by your program. I'd guess you think that `""I should be freed"` is created on stack and then destroyed or freed somehow, and that is a wrong assumption because that is a constant string literal and it is placed into program data segment and is "alive" for the life of your program.

And even if it was allocated dynamically and freed automatically upon leaving the scope, you still cannot expect your program to receive `SIGSEGV` in that case. Because undefined behavior does not always result in segmentation faults.

Also, try to never write `char *data = "blah-blah";`. String literals are assumed to always be constant and trying to modify them is undefined behavior. Though people still hack around this [sometimes](http://lazarenko.me/2013/05/01/how-constant-is-a-constant/).

Comment: ok, thanks, if I define it as char line[80]="I should be freed";, it should be allocated in stack, yes?

Comment: @gekannt Yes, `line` resides on stack. And the string literal is copied into the array.

Comment: @gekannt: Yes, that will trigger undefined behavior, but not necessarily a segmentation fault because stack memory is technically still there. So by chance it may still work, or it may print garbage, or crash.

Answer (score 2):

```
 char *line = "I should be freed";
```

You still see the content because the string literals has static storage duration. Here the string literal `I should be freed` resides in read only location and is freed once the program execution completes.

The program has no undefined behavior.